# Migrating from LoadRunner/The Grinder to JMeter: Where are the Scripts?

Tags: testing, load, jmeter, loadrunner, grinder

I've done load tests for users building scripts in LoadRunner or The Grinder, and now I'm trying out JMeter and it all feels incredibly clunky. Where are the scripts? Does everything have to be done through the UI? Is JMeter able to do complex scripting?

Answer (score 2):

JMeter has good user friendly GUI. We create scripts in JMeter using the UI. JMeter saves the script in XML format with .JMX extension. Script creation is NOT very difficult as you say.

- Check this [site](http://blazemeter.com/blog/get-started-scripting-jmeter) to get an idea.
- Complex scripting can be done in JMeter using  logic controllers.

Also JMeter

- Is Free & Open source
- Is Light weight & easy to install
- supports any platform
- Supports many protocols - HTTP/HTTPS, FTP, SOAP, LDAP, JDBC, JMS, SMTP, POP etc
- Supports external plugins
- Can be extended with Beanshell scripts, Groovy, Javascript, Java.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried out Jmeter briefly but I think to it's for you to try it out yourself, there are a number of Jmeter tutorials on the Jmeter site itself as well as on youtube which should prove useful.

Below are some links:

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/intro.html

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cv7KqxaLZd8

Hope these links help you in getting a better understanding of Jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

What do you call "scripts"?

JMeter is designed so anyone could create tests using UI only. JMeter's [Logic Controllers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers), [Pre](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#preprocessors)/[Post-Processors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#assertions), etc. are quite enough to build a load test of any complexity.

If you feel yourself too creative and you're limited by JMeter Test Elements you're welcome to extend it using

- Code-enabled test elements like BSF, Beanshell, JSR-223 Pre/PostProcessors, Samplers, Timers and Assertions
- Developing custom functions
- Developing custom implementation of [Java Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) Sampler
- Developing custom implementation of your own Sampler or Function
- Finally it is possible [to either run existing or create new tests](http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) using [JMeter API](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, that answers my question!